# Android onLocationChanged stopped being called

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I have a fragment:

```
public  class myMap extends Fragment implements LocationListener
{
  // do all the usual stuff
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(mIsGPSEnabled)
    {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, this);
    }
    // and of course a bit more of code I am skipping
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "location changed  " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

I noticed the following behavior:

1. onResume gets always the last known location that works fine.
2. Upon start of the app on my notification bar I see this little icon that GPS is on
3. after a while I get the onLocationChanged called the first time (so far all is fine)
4. now the little GPS icon vanishes from the notification bar and onLocationChanged is never called again. The app is at all times in the forground
5. I never unregister (for now) my location change listener
6. I bring my app in the backround and start for example osmand (a navigation software) while this software is running I see my toast in onLocationChanged on every update, working as it should.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: are you sure it isnt requesting updates you have the minimum request time set to 1 minute so you wont be getting updates for a minute at least

Comment: yes I am sure, waited 15 minutes walking around town...

Comment: do you test on HTC Hero?

Answer (score 0):

Check if

> mLocationManager != null

if is null you can requesteLocationUpdates otherwise avoids to call requests

Comment: I checked that in the debugger, it is not null. If it would be null then even the first update wouldn't work, but this works.

Comment: OK but is wrong to call requesteUpdates multiple times. You should call once.

Answer (score 0):

Use Log and watch it using [free logcat app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) or this to be sure that your location not updated:

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location changed  " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

because i don't think that your default home screen is an activity! that's why toasts appear in osmand and your app and don't in home screen.

so i think you are in a famous android location api issue that i spent more than 30 days before knowing that there lot of peoples have the same problem!, than you can feel better if you take a look here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707

the problem have no limit no algorithm no special cases : >> get first location, stop for a while, work perfectly for two days and switch work n stop for a week... !!

I think you must buy new test phone!